# recursive X^N algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've two C programs

where input N should be any integer 2^n : n>=1

one is-

```
int power(int x,int n)
{
if(n==2)
return x*x;
else
return power(x,n/2)*power(x,n/2);
}
int main()
{
    int x=6;
    int n=8;
    printf("%d",power(x,n));
    getch();
}
```

Other one is-

```
int power(int x,int n)
{
if(n==2)
return x*x;
else
{
int result=power(x,n/2);
return result*result;
}
}
int main()
{
    int x=6;
    int n=8;
    printf("%d",power(x,n));
    getch();
}
```

For the first one time complexity function will be-

`T(n)=2T(n/2)+c` hence by deriving we will get `O(log n)`

For the last one it will be-

`T(n)=T(n/2)+c` hence by deriving we will get `O(log n)`

is it correct?

Comment: for first one `T(n) = O(n)`, and for the second `T(n) = 0(log n) `

Comment: how can you please explain?

Comment: first run your functions with arguments `2, 3` and see what happens then I'll explain. your base case should be `n == 0` mate

Comment: The input must be 2^n where  n>=1. Sorry I forgot to put this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first relation you actually have

```
T(n) = 2 T(n/2)+c = 2^2*T(n/2^2) + 2c+c = ...
= 2^(k-1)*T(n/2^(k-1)) + (k-1)*c+(k-2)*c+...+c =
= 2^(k-1)*T(2) + (k-1)*k*c/2 = n/2 + c*(log n-1)(log n)/2 = O(n)
```

since you have that `n=2^k` and the `n/2` dominates `c*(log n)^2` (as `n` goes to infinity `n/2` becomes much larger than `c*(log n)^2`).

For the second one you are right:

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2)+c  = T(n/2^2) + 2c = ... = T(n/2^(k-1)) + (k-1)c = T(2)+(k-1)*c= 
= 1 + c*(logn-1) = O(log n)
```

Comment: Got it. First one will be `O(n)`.
But I think that there is a mistake in your derivation
`T(n) = 2 T(n/2)+c = 2^2*T(n/2^2) + 2c + c = .... = 2^(k-1)*T(n/2^(k-1)) + (k-1)*c + .... + c = n + c*(n/2 -1)`

Comment: @AnuragChakraborty yea, you are right. fixed it. the complexity stays the same though.